# Why does "i8042.dumbkbd" fix the issue where my keyboard doesn't respond after logging in, and is there a way to fix it some other way?

Tags: grub2, keyboard, 22.04, login, lg

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 on an LG gram 2-in-1 laptop. My computer used to have a problem where the keyboard would be unresponsive for a few minutes after I turned it on, but I was able to easily find the solution: adding `i8042.dumbkbd=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`. This seems like a very common issue.

The thing is, when I [looked up](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=233450) what the option means, it said it makes the computer unable to control the keyboard's state. While this explains the fact that my indicator lights aren't working, I am confused as to why this would have anything to do with the original issue with my keyboard.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me what is happening with my keyboard when I don't have this option enabled that it has to become unresponsive for a few minutes. Also, I would like to know if there is a way to fix this issue without having to disable my indicator light.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: looking at the kernel source code they make i8042.dumbkbd = true , for some of HP laptops they know will work only with this . So whatever you put it in boot parameters  , or they enable it in kernel code for your laptop , looks to be same fix , and they for now do not have another fix than enabling it for you in code . How kernel i8042 module work with your keyboard when dumbkbd is false and make your keyboard not working is related how it communicate with the keyboard read only keyboard events or also send events . For some reason the keyboard do not respond to the driver init events